# Calculating average acceleration

Tags: kinematics, unit-of-measure

I have the question "A train accelerates from rest to a speed of 155kmh^-1 in a time of 3 minutes 45 seconds. Calculate it's average acceleration over this time in units of ms^-2"

I know the velocity is 155 kmh^-1 and time is 225 seconds when changed from minutes to seconds and that the subject of the equation has to be A (acceleration) but I am unsure which equation to use to solve this.

Comment: You need to convert the target speed to m/s too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\gamma=\frac{v_1-v_0}{t_1-t_0}$

with $t_1-t_0=3\times 60 +45$ s.

which gives

$\frac{ \frac{  155000}{3600}  }{  225    }$ in $ms^{-2}$

$=\frac{1550}{36\times225}$

$=\frac{310}{36\times45}$

$=\frac{31}{18\times9}$

$=\frac{31}{162}=0.191 ms^{-2}$.

Comment: Okay so I converted the time to seconds and got 225 [s] and converted the velocity from 155 [kmh^-1] to 43.1 [ms^-1] I then used the equation a = v / t and got the answer a = 0.192[ms^-2] is this correct ?

Comment: @Dan is it ok now?

Comment: Acceleration should have the unit ms^-2 so should your final answer not have this unit ?

Comment: @Dan of course friend.